# How to get the line number in TextEdit

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text-editor, big-sur

Is it possible to get or display the line number in TextEDit in macOS Big Sur?

As I am using the editor for HDL (Hardware Descriptive Language) coding. If it's not possible, could you point me to an editor that supports line numbers that I could use with HDL files?

[image]

Comment: **TextEdit** does not have that feature, like some other editors do.

Comment: Import text into excel or numbers, add line numbers in a column, concatenate and export back to the text editor. Pain if you then add a line, but you did ask for « any way »...

Comment: What is HDL coding?

Comment: @nohillside , HDL  means Hardware descriptive language it is similar as Verilog or VHDL .For the hardware programming like chips and Alu's in a processor.

Comment: I assume this are basically text files (because TextEdit wouldn't work on them otherwise). So you can use any **text** editor for this.

Comment: @HarikrishnaGoli CotEditor (https://coteditor.com) is an excellent, free open-source editor that not only has line numbering but also syntax highlighting support for the two major hardware description languages, VHDL and Verilog. It supports Big Sur and can be downloaded from the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/app/coteditor/id1024640650?ls=1

Comment: Thanks @jaume for the recommendation

Answer (score 7):

I typically use the App Store app to download BBEdit since it runs for free and has all the things you would want including line numbers. If you are familiar with VSCode, that’s a solid option too, but it is not a native app like BBEdit and TextEdit are.

I’m fairly sure there is no line number function in TextEdit.

- http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html
- https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: +1 for BBEdit, which is the de facto 'serious' text editor on the Mac, and has been for c.30 years. TextEdit is not good enough for coding.

Comment: I’m rolling back the suggestion to use https://coteditor.com/ since I’ve never heard of it. It looks promising, but I can’t recommend it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs. It has plugins for everything. HDL is built in. Line numbers are toggled in menu. Emacs-plus is a solid recommendation.

Vim is another good choice, but I don’t know if it supports out of the box HDL.